# My actionbar shows as blank when i resuming from other activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androiddesignsupport, android-coordinatorlayout

i am developing an app using with design support library  compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'. xml code of my activity design is given bellow.
http://prntscr.com/89in6t

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

here,actionbar is show/hide depending on scrolling.
my problem is when actionbar is hide and go to other activity and finish it,  come back to same activity. at the time actionbar is shown as blank like this

http://prntscr.com/89iw4y

how can solve?

Comment: Perhaps you need to handle it in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: No, i do not take any result from new activity. so onActivityResult is not needed.

Comment: But it could be used to know when the new activity finishes, so that you can refresh the ActionBar. Or you can just use `onResume()` and refresh the ActionBar somehow.

Comment: but i recalled the ActionBar in onResume, but no use

Comment: yes.. i got it. bellow answer is working properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the Design Support Library.

I solved it by adding an empty `View` below my `Toolbar`.